# Set default action for home button in action bar for all activities

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I want to declare an activity my app's 'home' activity. Now, I can setup the action of home button in each activity using

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                HomeScreen.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've declared my HOME activity in manifest using

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomeScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</activity>
```

I've also enabled the showHome option of actionBar using

```
<style name="ActionBarCustom" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/arrow_icon</item>
</style>
```

Now, when I click my home button from an activity where I've not specified

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

specifically, it doesn't show the indication that the button has been clicked. I want a default action for my home button. I know I'm missing a very small thing if I'm right. I've gone through a lot of stuff on stack overflow & developer.android but all in vain. Can anyone please help? **I want to set a default action for home button.**

In addition I may also want to setup a custom action bar using showCustom but again **I want to define a default action for the other button** (I want to setup in action bar) at one place rather than specifying it in every activity).

(I'm testing on android 2.2.)

Answer (score 0):

you missed

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Oh no! This code works absolutely fine (The one I've posted in my question). But that is for one activity whereas I want to define a default action for all my activities.

Comment: & now it seems that it doesn't have any other solution than creating a base activity & then extending all other activities from the base activity. :/

Comment: Btw for use of homeAsUp refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP)

Comment: Yes your question was a bit unclear. what do you want achieve

Comment: you have to create a super class that extends Activity, and put inside it all the code common to the other activities. The other have to extends your class

Comment: @ShivamMangla This is oop after all!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Activity call it BaseActivity.

Now derive all activities where you want the functionality and override the  onOptionsItemSelected there